# How to make an application start on factory reset/first startup?

Tags: android, startup

I am looking to have some basic forms run on my android device after it is reset or on the first boot like most smartphones ask you to connect to Wi-Fi, register the device etc. I haven't worked with native android development previously so what are my options and what areas should I look into?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

BootCompleteReceiver.java

```
public class BootCompleteReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {   

    @Override  
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {  

        Intent service = new Intent(context, MsgPushService.class);  
        context.startService(service);   

    }  

}
```

MyService.java

```
public class MyService extends Service {  


    @Override  
    public void onCreate() {  
        super.onCreate();    
    }  

    @Override  
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {  

        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return Service.START_STICKY;  
    }  

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroy", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override  
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {  
        return null;  
    }  
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.newbootservice"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <service android:name=".MyService"/>

        <receiver android:name=".BootCompleteReceiver">  
            <intent-filter>     
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>  
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />  
            </intent-filter>  
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```